# Touchpad has stopped working on Dell XPS 13 Plus 9320 running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: 22.04, mouse, touchpad, xps, libinput

Dell XPS 13 Plus 9320 Developer Edition: Core i5-1240P, 16GB RAM, 1 TB SSD, 1920x1200 display non-touch

Kernel: 5.19.0-40-generic

After a week of use, the touchpad (VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1) has completely stopped working (earlier intermittent, now permanent). It seems that the kernel fails to recognize it. Issue also appears with older kernels all the way up to v5.15.

During boot, the following error appears:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep VEN_04F3:00
[    7.998712] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-VEN_04F3:00: failed to reset device: -61
[   14.142687] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-VEN_04F3:00: failed to reset device: -61
[   27.454738] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-VEN_04F3:00: can't add hid device: -61
```

The trackpad is not visible anymore:

```
$ xinput list
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Dell touchpad firmware has been updated to the latest version.(https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=yd0v6&oscode=ubt22&productcode=xps-13-9320-laptop) 2023.04.03.423, A02, as of 23-04-2023. Issue still persists.

Dell BIOS has been updated to the latest [version](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=mh38g&oscode=ubt22&productcode=xps-13-9320-laptop) 2.1.0 as of 23-04-2023. The issue still persists.

Switching from Wayland to X11 has no effect.

Also adding the following to grub does not help:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0 i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"`

Does anyone have a similar experience? Also, please share what other Linux distributions you have been using on your XPS laptop. I might give then a try.

Filed a bug report with Ubuntu: [2017413](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.19/+bug/2017413)

Comment: Have you checked it's not a hardware failure (eg does it work in the Bios menu, or try in a live session)?