Touchpad erratic behavious on wake up Dell Dell XPS 13 9320
I am going crazy here with a touchpad issue on my Dell running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Description:
Initial problem: On wake up my touchpad behaves erratically, becoming sticky (the selection remains on dragging things around randomly, selecting text and icons, making random clicks). One finger touch click does not work (there are no physical buttons on this laptop). Two finger touch click always works. Sometime the two finger scrolling stops working (but not always). Rebooting the systems fixes the issue.
After testing a few solutions (for example [here][1]) to no success, now the touchpad is showing the same behaviors even during a normal session, and not only on wake up from suspension or hybernate. This usually happens after I spend a few minute writing, making me think that this is a power management issue (the touchpad is "suspended" and when reawaken something goes wrong).
Currently I am spending more time trying to work than actually working, and this is becoming unsustainable! Please help!!
Temporary Solution:
Disabling and enabling the touchpad fixes the issue momentarily:
xinput disable 'VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1 Touchpad' && xinput enable 'VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1 Touchpad'

But often I need to repeat this multiple times while working. My guess is that it is a power management issue on the touchpad. No problem with external mouse.
Here all the relevant info:
System: Dell XPS 13 9320 2023, 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1360P × 16, 32 Gb RAM
$uname -r
Linux 6.5.0-1023-oem #24-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 14:26:31 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$lspci
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device a707
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device a7a0 (rev 04)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a71d
0000:00:05.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Device a75d
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a76e
0000:00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a72f
0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device a74f
0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a77d (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a71e
0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a73e
0000:00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a76d
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Device a77f
0000:00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 51fc (rev 01)
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 51f1 (rev 01)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH UART #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:1e.3 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ab (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 519d (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a74d
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 1959

$xinput
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1 Mouse               id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1 Touchpad            id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Privacy Driver                       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]


$dmesg | grep VEN_04F3:00
[    1.787770] input: VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-VEN_04F3:00/0018:04F3:31D1.0001/input/input5
[    1.787879] input: VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-VEN_04F3:00/0018:04F3:31D1.0001/input/input6
[    1.787928] input: VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-VEN_04F3:00/0018:04F3:31D1.0001/input/input8
[    1.787966] hid-generic 0018:04F3:31D1.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1] on i2c-VEN_04F3:00
[    3.699467] input: VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-VEN_04F3:00/0018:04F3:31D1.0001/input/input11
[    3.699553] input: VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-VEN_04F3:00/0018:04F3:31D1.0001/input/input12
[    3.699617] input: VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1 UNKNOWN as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-VEN_04F3:00/0018:04F3:31D1.0001/input/input14
[    3.699667] hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:31D1.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1] on i2c-VEN_04F3:00

$dmidecode -s bios-version
2.10.0

$sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date
02/02/2024

$xinput list-props 9
Device 'VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (189):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (191): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (348): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (349): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (350):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (351):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (352):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (353):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (354):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (355):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (327):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (328):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (356):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (357):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (329):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (330):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (331):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (358): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (359):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (360):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (361):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (362):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (336): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (337): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (338):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (339):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (340):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (341): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (342): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (312): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (313):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (314):    0, 0
    Device Node (315):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (316):    1267, 12753
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (343):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (344):   1
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (345):    15
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (346):    15
    libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (347):    1


  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464924/touchpad-has-stopped-working-on-dell-xps-13-plus-9320-running-ubuntu-22-04-2-lts


OK, no suggestions yet. Am I the only one with this problem?

I've had a similar issue. It always goes away after a minute or two, so until recently I hadn't spend any time trying to investigate the issue. Does it not resolve itself on its own for you?
